# Changing home directory on WSL gets rid of all color schemes in cmder

Tags: bash, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm quite used to competitive programming on linux so I was trying to set up bash in WSL. To run the executable I found out I need to type out the whole path like `/mnt/e/...` So I thought by changing the home directory would be easier because then I can just go for: `~/program.exe` but changing the home directory gets rid of the color scheme in cmder, making it a bit harder to read.

- Before:

[image]

- After:

[image]

To change the home directory I followed these steps:

1. Enter bash
2. Type the command sudo vim /etc/passwd
3. Find my account's line
   : `kalia:x:1000:1000:"",,,:/home/kalia:/bin/bash`
4. Replace `/home/kalia` with the directory I wanted the home directory to be.
5. Saved the changes and then restarted bash

Comment: How did you change the home directory? Please provide all the steps that you have done in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've added the steps I took. Thankyou. @Biswapriyo

Answer (score 0):

While experimenting, I did find a solution. the `.bashrc` file contained all the information about styling the thing so I just simply copied over all the files from the original home directory to the new home directory and that fixed it. I don't know if it is the most optimal thing to do but I don't seem to have any errors as of now.